# Saving in Core Data not working

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using the following core data saving code and it is not saving.
The managedObjectContext is passed by a factory class that is providing a new context.

```
- (void)save{
NSError *error = nil;
// save the data in context
if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
    if ([managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        if (error) {
            DEBUGLOG(@"%@ saving faild with error code: %ld and message: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), (long)error.code, error.localizedDescription);
        }
        else{
            DEBUGLOG(@"%@ managedObjectContext save success!!!!!!!!", NSStringFromClass([self class]));
            // succesufuly saved data
            [self updateLastSuccessSyncGet];
        }
    }
    else{
        DEBUGLOG(@"%@ managedObjectContext save failed!!!!!!!!", NSStringFromClass([self class]));
        DEBUGLOG(@"%@ saving failed with error code: %ld and message: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), (long)error.code, error.localizedDescription);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is [managedObjetContext save:] returning an error? Is [managedObjectContext hasChanges] returning NO when it shouldn't? Are you checking to make sure managedObjectContext isn't nil? I need some more detail here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which kind of queue concurrency type are you using? Generally it happens because you are running in a thread. In this case you should use the private concurrency type, like:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

Comment: in this case you'll also have to call save inside a performBlock block.